# How do I create a VSTS Build for a Pull Request?

Tags: git, build, azure-devops

I am trying to create a Build definition in VSTS to run when Pull Requests are made. I have already set up a CI build for the `master` branch but want to run a separate build on each PR before merging (ideally automatically) into master. I understand branch policies but am having trouble creating the actual Build definition.

When I try to configure the build the `Get Sources` task requires a branch name, which I don't have when it comes to Pull Requests. How do I create a Build definition just for Pull Requests (where the branch name is unknown)?

Comment: This [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#require-a-successful-build) talks about configuring a specific build definition to run for each PR.  I think that might work for you.

Comment: Once a branch policy is configured and a build is assigned, VSTS will create a temporary branch to merge the Feature branch into the destination branch in the Pull Request, and then it will pass that branch name to the build automatically. You don't need to worry about the branch as VSTS will handle it.

Comment: @PatrickSteele I've read through all of those and all they say is make a build definition. My confusion is around getting the sources from the PR rather than the branch I choose from a dropdown.

Comment: @DenverDev was right in the fact that when I create that build definition the branch I choose will automatically be overridden with the PR branch. If you could create an answer with your explanation I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those things that 'just works' without you actually needing to think about it.

1. Create the build definition that you want to be triggered by the pull request. This can be a specific build for pull requests only, or it can be a build that is multi purpose. **You will need to select a branch in the 'Get Sources' step, but VSTS will overwrite this value with a branch that is dynamically created by the pull request**
2. Navigate to Code -> Manage Repositories and follow the instructions to create a [Branch Policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#require-a-successful-build). You will want to follow the instructions under 'Require a successful build'
3. Create a Pull Request from you feature branch to the branch that you configured a policy for in step #2 and you will see that VSTS kicks off a build for you using a dynamically created branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Branch Policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/branch-policies#require-a-successful-build). That will allow you to reuse your existing CI build and have it automatically run as part of any PR opened against the specified branch.

Comment: I understand the overall process very well, my question was regarding the small step of choosing a branch when getting the sources in the Build definition.

Comment: You don't change anything in the build definition. When the build is queued via the branch policy, the branch to build is set automatically.